# Laravel 5.3 Blade - Get available sections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Currently I am working on a custom CMS for Laravel where I need to get all available sections of a certain blade view. These sections will be rendered in a form where an user can fill them with content.

Lets say I have this view:

```
// view.blade.php
@section ('left_column')

@endsection

@section ('right_column')

@endsection
```

I would be nice if I can retrieve these sections in some sort of array and render them in the form. Anyone knows this is possible with existing methods? I could not find any helpful methods in the Laravel files.

If not, I will write a custom method (or some sort) to retrieve these sections and post it as an answer.

Comment: Okay I found out the ViewFactory that generates the view and has a method named `getSections`. However when a view gets generated it flushes some variables at the end like the sections array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be like:

```
public function get_view_sections ($view) // $view should be like page.index
{

    # Create file name and path
    #
    $file_name = preg_replace('/\./', '/', $view).'.blade.php';

    $path = resource_path('views/'.$file_name);


    # Get file content
    #
    $file = File::get($path);


    # Get sections
    #
    $matches = [];

    preg_match_all('/(?<=\@section\(\').*?(?=\'\))/', $file, $matches);


    return $matches[0];

}
```

This will return something like:

```
[
    'left_column',
    'right_column'
]
```

**Edit**

Changed: `preg_match` to `preg_match_all`

Changed: `return $matches` to `return $matches[0]`